# ML - Labelling - number of possibilities

Tags: machine-learning, classification, multilabel-classification

I've started learning ML and stuck with the number of possibilities in labelling. I have a sample which comprises 4 attributes (binary) (from the book Apprentissage artificiel, Antoine Cornéujols) number: 1 or 2 sizes: small or large color: red or green form: square or circle

Considering those 4 binary attributes, there are 16 different cases.

I am looking for functions that could explain the labeling, ie depending on those 4 attributes, the outcome can be + or -.

Now, the issue is that it says that there are 2^2^4=65.536 possible functions.

I would have expected it to be 16*2 and not 2^16

many thanks in advance as I am stuck page 47 of this book which counts 900 of them;...

Answer (score 1):

A function which "explains the labelling" has to map any value from the input set $X$ to a value in the output set $Y$.
Let's try a more simple example with $X=\{a,b,c\}$ and $Y=\{0,1\}$. The possible functions are:

- $a \mapsto 0, b \mapsto 0, c \mapsto 0$
- $a \mapsto 0, b \mapsto 0, c \mapsto 1$
- $a \mapsto 0, b \mapsto 1, c \mapsto 0$
- $a \mapsto 0, b \mapsto 1, c \mapsto 1$
- $a \mapsto 1, b \mapsto 0, c \mapsto 0$
- $a \mapsto 1, b \mapsto 0, c \mapsto 1$
- $a \mapsto 1, b \mapsto 1, c \mapsto 0$
- $a \mapsto 1, b \mapsto 1, c \mapsto 1$

One may notice that we need to enumerate every possible assignment of the 3 input variables, because each of them is a different function. This can be represented as a tree where each node represents the choice for an input variable to be assigned any of the output variable, so a node has $|Y|$ children and a depth of $|X|$. The number of leaves in such a tree is $|Y|^{|X|}$. In my above example this is $2^3=8$. In the question example this would be $2^{16}$.

Comment: many thanks Erwan for your answer, very clear with the tree. I can continue my journey in ML....